# OOP Javascript parent Object method or Object?

Tags: javascript

```
var O = {

    elements: {

        main: function() { return jQuery("#main"); },
        footer: function() { return jQuery("#footer"); }
    },

    main: function(html) {

        return (this.elements.main());
    },


    style: {

        setMaincolor: function() {

            // TypeError: Cannot call method 'main' of undefined
            return (this.elements.main());

        }

    }    

};
```

so;  I'm  O.style Object parents Objects ????

```
O.style.setMaincolor() // TypeError: Cannot call method 'main' of undefined
O.main() // [<div id=​"main">​</div>​]
```

setMaincolor method return this to O Object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` refers to the object on which the method was invoked.

`main()` is invoked on the `O` object, so `this` is a reference to `O`. Therefore `this.elements === O.elements`.

`setMaincolor()` is invoked on the `style` object, so `this` will be a reference to `O.style`, which does not have an `.elements` property.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly define what `this` should mean; if not specified, `this` will point to the nearest object.

You can create a closure for it like so:

```
var O = (function() {
    var self = {
        elements: {
            main: function() { return jQuery("#main"); },
            footer: function() { return jQuery("#footer"); }
        }
    }

    self.style = {
        setMaincolor: function() {
            return self.elements.main();
        }
    }

    return self;
}());
```

The `(function() { ... }());` returns the object and the `self` is a "private" variable that only the `O` object knows about and it points to itself, thereby making the `.elements.main()` reference work.

Comment: You need to update your code example, a "return self" is missing.

Answer (score 1):

since the `setMaincolor` method is defined within the `style` object, `this` refers to the `style` object. Since the `style` object has no `elements` property, `this.elements` is undefined.

One solution would be something like this, where you name the `O` object explicitly instead of using `this`:

```
var O = {

    elements: {

        main: function() { return jQuery("#main"); },
        footer: function() { return jQuery("#footer"); }
    },

    main: function(html) {

        return (this.elements.main());
    },


    style: {

        setMaincolor: function() {

            // TypeError: Cannot call method 'main' of undefined
            return (O.elements.main());

        }

    }    

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference `this.elements` in your `setMaincolor` method. The `this`-pointer refers to your style-object: Use `O.elements.main()` in your `O.style.setMaincolor` function instead.

```
style: {
    setMaincolor: function() {
        return (O.elements.main());

    }
}
```

Although, I don't recommend this approach, note that you also can also use: `O.style.setMaincolor.call(O,[]);` which makes `this` reference `O`.

This is how I would have solved it:

```
var O = (function() {
   var self = {
       elements: {
           main: function() { return jQuery("#main"); },
           footer: function() { return jQuery("#footer"); }
       },

       main: function(html) {
           return self.elements.main();
       },

       style: {
           setMaincolor: function() {
               return self.elements.main();
           }
       }
   };    

   return self;    
}());
```